# What is wrong with my closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [how to modify a CSS Class according to the text contained inside, without using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145845/how-to-modify-a-css-class-according-to-the-text-contained-inside-without-using)

What is wrong with that question? I'm French so is it about my English? I wonder who is reviewing... Everything I write is quite understandable.

Comment: I don't think its about your english, but the question definitely lacks the html that you currently have. Linking to some external source is not enough. In addition, the pieces you show don't fit together. It *seems* you try to color based on the text. But then you talk about `getElementsByTagName` which searches by the name of the tag and there is no `pinyin` tag in HTML. It's also unclear where PHP comes into play. If you already generate this texts with PHP, then this is the place to start (but isn't shown). If it's a static page, then where should PHP intervene?

Comment: Not that it matters since the question has to be sefl-contained anyway, but the given login doesn't work for me.

Comment: It is *definitely* not about your [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/English#Noun). In terms of Stack Overflow, it is in the top 1%.

Comment: eh, probably also due to the fact that what you're asking for is... not possible in the way you're asking. You can't style individual words in a text block, you'd need to wrap them in a span or similar to style them individually... which would require parsing the text and wrapping said words using either javascript or php.

Answer (score 12):

I've read your question four times, and I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. The way to fix this is to show **what expected output would look like**, which the question does not.

Further, all questions on Stack Overflow must be **self-contained**, i.e. everything needed to answer the question must be in the question itself. It is not acceptable to say "please look at this external resource" because if that external resource goes away or changes, the question becomes meaningless. Again, your question fails this requirement.

Finally, your choice of tags makes no sense. This question appears to be about CSS only, why did you tag it as [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)? It contains no regular expressions, why did you tag it as [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)? This sort of tag spam is generally a hallmark of low-quality questions.

The first two factors make your question unanswerable in its current form, the third adds to the impression that it should be closed.

Answer (score 8):

It has been specified in the top of the question that it lacks clarity or details.

Try to include the HTML file to understand how the CSS would work, and to be more concise explaining the error. Just go straight to the point, instead of discussing which method could be better to solve it, or putting all your question/explanation before and all the code after that, as examples.